# Is there a way to store the results of a loop into a Sequence variable in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a list of names

```
names = ["David","Olivia","Charlotte"]
```

I want to measure the length of each name in this list and store the integer value in a list like L=[] and using the max function to determine which name is the longest. Something like below:

```
L = []
for x in names:
   L = len(x)
print(max(L))
```

but I get this error in the terminal that the defined L variable is not iterable. How do I store the results in L variable as a sequence?

Comment: You are assigning to `L` only one number, not actually appending to a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great use for a (list) comprehension:

```
names = ["David", "Olivia", "Charlotte"]
lengths = (len(name) for name in names)
print(max(lengths))
```

Above just uses a generator comprehension, but if you used brackets instead of parens you'd create a list:

```
lengths = [len(name) for name in names]
```

The generator is somewhat faster because you only move over the list once. `max()` lets you shorthand the generator:

```
print(max(len(name) for name in names))
```

`max()` also lets you do this:

```
max(names, key=len)
```

In this case, the `key` parameter is taking a function that returns a value that can be used to determine the maximum value. This returns the value of the longest item:

```
>>> names = ["David", "Olivia", "Charlotte"]
>>> max(names, key=len)
'Charlotte'
```

Alternatively, if you want to use `reduce` (a functional style approach), you can do this:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce( lambda x, y: max(x, len(y)), names, 0)
9
```

This moves through the list and compares a starting value (`0`) with the length of each new value (`len(y)`), and chooses one at each step. This is basically equivalent, but can be a useful alternative in more nuanced circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

`append` to the list, don't overwrite it.

```py
L: list[int] = []
for x in names:
   L.append(len(x))
print(max(L))
```

---

Actually, it's more efficient to create the list “on the fly”:

```py
L: list[int] = [len(x) for x in names]
print(max(L))
```

... or not to create a list at all:

```py
print(max(len(x) for x in names))
```

Comment: One-line version: `L = [len(name) for name in names]`

Comment: @0x5453, thank you, I was about to come to it. However, when I started learning Python, such concepts were hard for me to comprehend. I know that they are better practices, but they are less similar to other popular languages.

Answer (score 0):

If you just care about the longest name, there's no need to create a list at all:

```
max_length = 0
names = ["David","Olivia","Charlotte"]
for name in names:
    max_length = max(max_length, len(name))
```

---

Note that in this case, you can initialize `max_length` to 0 because no name can have less than 0 characters in it. In a more general case where you are dealing with quantities that might be negative, you can use `max_length=float('-inf')`, which obviously also works for this problem.